# Getting your jquery datatable to sort DESC by first column. Or setting another column as its default sortby

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been trying to figure this out now for a few hours and its not happening.  When I load my table I need for it to sort desc on the first col.  Here's what I have but no luck.

```
/**
*   Makes the table in the tabs for reports
*
* @param array Holds the data for datatable.
**/
var makeTabTable = function(tableData){
    $("#tab_active_reg").dataTable({
        bJQueryUI : true,
        bDestroy : true,
        aoColumns : [
            {"sTitle" : "Seen", "sWidth" : "50px", "asSorting": [ "desc"]},
            {"sTitle" : "Sold", "sWidth" : "50px"},
            {"sTitle" : "Name", "sWidth" : "240px"}
        ],
        aaData : tableData  
        });
    $('.tabsComponent').find('.fg-toolbar').empty();
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

just add this option to the `dataTable()` call:

```
aaSorting : [[0, 'desc']]
```

so in your case:

```
   $("#tab_active_reg").dataTable({
        bJQueryUI : true,
        bDestroy : true,
        aaSorting : [[0, 'desc']],
        aoColumns : [
            {"sTitle" : "Seen", "sWidth" : "50px"},
            {"sTitle" : "Sold", "sWidth" : "50px"},
            {"sTitle" : "Name", "sWidth" : "240px"}
        ],
        aaData : tableData  
    });
```

as you can see, it is an array of `[colnumber, sortdirection]`, so you can specify multiple.

Comment: I tried that and it's not working.  It keeps sorting on load asc.    aoColumns : [
    {"sTitle" : "Clicks", "sWidth" : "50px", "aaSorting" : [[0, 'asc']] },  Like this right?

Comment: you took out the asSorting in the column-def? and you specified ALL your columns in aoColumns (there are only 3 total). no errors in the console? it works for me...

Comment: thanks for spelling it out.  I keep trying to place it in the aoColumns.  I originally had it like it was suppose to be except that it was something like     aaSorting : [0, 'desc'].  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a more **simpler answer** as per the latest Datatable Documentations.

For example if you want to sort **4th Column** of the Data Table by **Descending Order** on ***default Load of page*** then use this code.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({    
     //We are simply using order property which is an array of array so multiple columns can be ordered like this.
            "order": [
                      [3, 'desc'],
      
                     ]        
            
        });
} );
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russell Chavez</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you also want to change the default click of columns to be sorted as **Descending Order** then you can [see this fiddle](http://live.datatables.net/zecugafo/1/edit?js) as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a version difference here?  I'll make it so people will know which answer is for them.  And update this accordingly.